# Why ScanConsistency gives TimeOutExection in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, timeoutexception, sql++, couchbase-java-api

I have a use case in which I want updated data from the Couchbase so when I query couchbase for the data simply like:

```
bucket.get.query(Query.simple(query))
```

It gives me updated data, upto some time , but as the size of the data base increases it does not provide me updated and consistent data.
Here the query is scanning an index and providing the required data accordingly.
So for getting the consistent data I used the ScanConsistency.REQUESTPLUS as suggested by [couchbase documentation.](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/architecture/querying-data-with-n1ql.html) But as soon as I change the code and do something like this:

```
bucket.get.query(Query.simple(query, QueryParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
        .serverSideTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
```

It gives me a timeout Exception each and everytime and never returns me the result. Can you please explain how can I achieve the consistency of the data here and why it is always giving me timeout exception.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
[error]     at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
[error]     at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.query(CouchbaseBucket.java:548)
[error]     at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.query(CouchbaseBucket.java:491)
```

Any help is appreciated.!

Comment: from the use of `QueryParams`, I see that you are using an outdated version of the SDK. Please use the 2.2 generation and Couchbase Server 4.0 or over for official stabilized support of N1QL.

Comment: Also you've increased the server side timeout, but you could try increasing the client-side timeout as well, by providing a duration and a TimeUnit in the bucket.get.query call

Comment: Hi @simon, could you please put this in an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of the SDK introduced **Experimental** support for N1QL before version `2.2.0`, which was the 1st version to officially support N1QL in a non-beta state (that is to say, in pair with Couchbase Server 4.0).

I notice that you don't use such a version, because `QueryParams` was renamed to `N1qlParams` in 2.2.0. So you need to upgrade to the latest SDK 2.2.x (2.2.5 should be out in a few days).

Also you can set a **server side** timeout (and you did in your example) but there is always a **client side** timeout (at least when you use the `Bucket` api). If you don't increase it in accordance to the server side timeout you set, you'll receive a `RuntimeException` wrapping a `TimeoutException` (the client side timeout will trigger).